# Can we really use Event Sourcing and CQRS , an event driven architecture for e-commerce checkout funnel?

Tags: events, domain-driven-design, microservices, event-sourcing

Let’s says Checkout has the following services:

1. Order service , creates order and collects shipping , payment and place an order and manages the life cycle of an order.
2. Inventory service, provides availability of products.
3. Shipping service  , provides delivery options and costs
4. Customer profile service, provides customer information.
5. Credit service, authorization of payment
6. Reservation service doing the reservation

Here is the flow of order creation :

Order is created, users provides shipping address, shipping options are calculated, payment is collected and order is placed and confirmation shown to user.

Many of retailers checkout are sync and order service orchestrating.

Let’s say if we are using event source , CQRS  and event store , order service creates an order event and persists in event store , publish the domain event and all other services subscribed to event store as they need to update the delivery  options , shipping cost , payment for to complete an order and using CQRS to inform user the status on each step for him to review.

I am trying to understand :

how complex the checkout application would be with all domain events of checkout like, adding shipping address, reservation, delivery option selection, adding payment and completing the order?

Would it be quicker than sync operation of order service orchestrating the checkout request ?

Would be eventual consistency in case of failure? How to handle evertual consistency ?

Answer (score 0):

Well we can use Event sourcing and CQRS for check out process. Like you said you would be raising events and subscribed services will react to that. How complex or easy is not the question , is it worth it in your case ? Event Sourcing and CQRS is complex pattern with many benefits but you need to implement it right way.

For eventual consistency you may have to rely on Saga Pattern where in case of failure you will have to raise compensating action for roll back.

Comment: Thanks Imran. Yes, is it worth doing ? That’s the valid question.  Event sourcing might not a good option , what about event driven architecture? Would it be good design for checkout ? I like the choreographic pattern over orchestration.

Comment: You can use event-driven architecture. Choreographic is a proffered approach .  Since check out process is critical so you need to design it that suits UI as well. e.g. you raise an event process payment . The user will have wait screen payment processing. Now if the payment service goes down , message broker goes down what you are you going to do  ? Eventually service will come and process but you can't keep your user hold for that long and if you timeout , user will think transaction is cancelled but at some point your payment event will be processed and you may charge client.

Comment: So you have to think all the aspects. Distributed transactions are complex and you have to design keeping in mind system will break. in this case event sourcing and CQRS is good since you have all the logs to track down any order.